# Reverse-Proxy Google site

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, google-sites-2016

We are trying to get a google site to run behind a proxy.
Spoke to a google support specialist and they said its possible, did not give any documentation and said to ask here.

A google website behind a nginx-proxy or Apache.
This proxy will be used to redirect traffic based on url.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This site is for questions about specific problems that are unique to programming. If it's  possible, [edit] the question to make it a good fit for this site (see [ask] and [help/on-topic]. Please note that questions about administering systems / networks might be off-topic if they are not direclty related to programming. There are other sites were they might be on-topic like [sf] and [su].